# Identifying relation's row not having rowed

Tags: sql, sqlite, indexing, row

I have a relation within SQLite DB. I have four columns and no id column. I need to delete row 3, for example. How can I write SQL query to identify that row number three amongst many other rows?
Best regards

Comment: For starters, how have you been able to identify the row as "row number 3"?

Comment: That supposed to be part of iOS app. A user selects custom cell and index of cell identifies the index of a row in relation where I store data regarding that cell.

Comment: If you don't have a primary key you will need to identify the row by matching every single one of its values. If you have the ability to do so, there's no excuse not to define a primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this.  Tables in SQL are inherently unordered.  So, the database has no concept of "third row" or first row or last row.

You need to modify the structure of the table to include a row number identifier.  Perhaps the easiest way is just to add an auto-increment id.  This works, unless you expected the database to keep track of deletes and updates that might change the ordering.

You can compare each value, but that has problems if duplicates are present in the data.

Answer (score 0):

delete from table where column1=.. and column2=.. and column3=.. and column4=..

With the where clause you find the row witch you will delete